# Indices for in-memory databases?

Tags: in-memory-database, indices

I am just researching about indices for databases. So far I have only found the index structures T-Tree and Adaptive Radix Tree. Are there more index structures ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different types of database indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319425/different-types-of-database-indexes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out our YouTube channel, https://www.youtube.com/user/McObject/videos,  which has some vendor-neutral tutorials on different types of indexes. Any index can implemented in memory. We implemented b-tree, r-tree, kd-tree, patricia trie, hash, and trigram indexes in our IMDS.